# Data type problems

Tags: c++, c, types

Can you  explain to me why this doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double data_convert(int n);

int main(void) {
    cout << data_convert(sizeof(int));
}

double data_convert(int n) {
    int i;
    double x;

    x = 8 * n;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        x = x * 32;
    return x;
}
```

I tried using pow from cmath, but I got the same results. Apparently, this outputs "4.67681e+049". Where as it should output (using Windows Calculator) "4294967296".

The for loop is my own hardcoded `pow()` function for this specific task. All I wanna do is make a program that can show how big a data type is, along with it's range (bit range or something, yeah?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `2^32`, you should be multiplying by 2 each time. Your code multiplies by 32 each time, so you'll end up with a much larger value.

Also, your `x` value should start from 1. `8 * n` is actually the number of bits in the integer, so that should be your upper limit for the loop:

```
x = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 8 * n; i++)
  x = x * 2;
return x;
```

A simpler method would be to bitwise negate 0, which will give you the largest possible integer:

```
return ~0;
```

will give you 2^32 - 1 = 4294967295 (on a 32-bit machine).

Comment: And adding casting to whatever integer datatype that needs testing should work I suppose.

Comment: Nice, no wonder I failed math in high school. Thank you very much

Comment: `~0` is wrong. First you suppose that your integers are represented in two's complement, which they mustn't. And even then, the number the OP is looking for is just not representable as an `int` but only as an `unsigned int`. `(unsigned)-1` would have been the answer that always works. In two's complement the number you have given would be (int)-1.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Agreed, I never gave a thought about a non-two's complement computer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are multiplying the input by 8 and are then multiplying that by 32, 32 times.

I don't understand what that is suppose to get you to.

If you want the range of an unsigned integer for x amount of bytes you should use this calculation:

max number = 2^(bytes*8) - 1

So in the loop it should multiply 2 until i goes from 0 to bytes*8 and stop there (So it ends before it gets to bytes*8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but don't you mean`x = x*2`?